# Move items across between multiple select

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two multi selects *viz*. `mySelectNumberTest1` and `mySelectNumberTest2`. What I want to do is be able to select items in the first dropdown and when I click on a checkbox/button or any control that will trigger an event, it should take the options from `mySelectNumberTest1` and populates it into `mySelectNumberTest2`.

I have followed this link: [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript/1085810#1085810) its a partial solution to my problem. The only thing that's missing is that if you select more than one item in `mySelectNumberTest1` it will only take the first item and populate it into `mySelectNumberTest2`.

The below code only works when I am populating items from a select into a normal input textbox.

```
 <select id="mySelectNumberTest1" name="mySelectNumberTest" multiple="multiple">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
 </select>
<input  type="checkbox" id="tickHereToMove" />
<input id="mySelectNumberTest2" name="mySelectNumberTest2" type="text" onchange="copyTextValueTest(this);" />


function copyTextValueTest(bf) {
    var e = document.getElementById("mySelectNumberTest1");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("mySelectNumberTest2").value = strUser;
    alert(strUser);
}
```

There's also a few problems with this approach as it concatenates the text. I tried the .split() function and that still didn't give me the result I wanted. I want the selected items in each line on `mySelectNumberTest2`.

This library http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/ does EXACTLY what I want to do. I am working in an Angular JS project and when I try include the jquery scripts in my `index.html` page, it causes anomalous behaviour and messes up the styling of the page as well.

So if I select `1` and `3` in `mySelectNumberTest1`, it should populate it in `mySelectNumberTest2` in two different lines and not `12`.

If this can be achieved in a drag and drop implementation I would also be happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this:

```js
function addOptions( fromId, toId ) {
    var fromEl = document.getElementById( fromId ),
        toEl = document.getElementById( toId );

    if ( fromEl.selectedIndex >= 0 ) {
        var index = toEl.options.length;

        for ( var i = 0; i < fromEl.options.length; i++ ) {
            if ( fromEl.options[ i ].selected ) {
                toEl.options[ index ] = fromEl.options[ i ];
                i--;
                index++
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70px 40px 70px;
    grid-gap: 10px
}
select {
    width: 70px
}
li.relative {
    position: relative
}
#add {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    font-size: 18px;
    top: 0
}
#remove {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    font-size: 18px;
    bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <select id="select1" name="select1" multiple>
            <option>Item 1</option>
            <option>Item 2</option>
            <option>Item 3</option>
            <option>Item 4</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li class="relative">
        <input  type="button" id="add" value="&#8702;" onclick="addOptions( 'select1', 'select2' )" />
        <input  type="button" id="remove" value="&#8701;" onclick="addOptions( 'select2', 'select1' )" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <select id="select2" name="select2" multiple></select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're a life saver dude!